# If $R$ is a ring with identity and $R\left[X\right]\cong R\left[Y\right]$, is it true that $\left|X\right|=\left|Y\right|$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and let $X$ and $Y$ be sets.  If $R\left[X\right]\cong R\left[Y\right]$, then is it true that $\left|X\right|=\left|Y\right|$? Here, $R\left[X\right]$ is the polynomial ring over $R$ with indeterminates in $X$. It looks like the result is true if $X$ and $Y$ are finite and $R$ is a field, since if $X$ and $Y$ are finite with size $n$ and $m$, respectively, and $n \neq m$, then the rings $R\left[X\right]$ and $R\left[Y\right]$ would have Krull dimension $n$ and $m$, respectively, and so would not be isomorphic. Is there a way to extend this argument to the case where $X$ and $Y$ are any arbitrary sets  and  $R$ is any ring with identity? Or does a counterexample exist?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio yes, yes, I need coffee. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the isomorphism is not assumed to be the $R$-algebra one, i.e. identity on $R$, then the answer is no. E.g. let $R=\mathbb Z[x_1, x_2, \cdots]$, then $R\simeq R[x]\simeq R[y_1, y_2]$. Otherwise the answer is yes.

If necessary, we can pick a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$, so we have $(R/\mathfrak m)[X]\simeq (R/\mathfrak m)[Y]$, thus we may assume $R$ is a field. And $R[X]\simeq R[Y]$ implies the fraction fields $R(X)\simeq R(Y)$. Since $X$ (resp. $Y$) is a transcendental basis of $R(X)$ (resp. $R(Y)$), we have $|X|=|Y|$ due to the invariance of the transcendental degree.

Edit: There is another way to finish the argument: If $X$ or $Y$ is finite, then use the Krull dimension for field $R$. Otherwise, the dimension of $R[X]$ as a $R$-vector space is $|X|$, as the set of monomials has the same cardinality as $X$ when $X$ is infinite.